# Empty composite field based on 3 columns when 1 column is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I'm having some problems with this query in SQL Server 2012. Whenever the `postalcode` is empty the entire `ELSE` statement will provide a null.

I tried the `Concat` function but it is not recognized as a function in this SQL Server version. Please advice

```
CASE 
   WHEN adres.CD_land = 'NL' THEN (street) 
   ELSE upper(postalcode + ' '+street) 
END as Street,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`COALESCE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
CASE 
   WHEN adres.CD_land = 'NL' THEN street 
   ELSE upper(COALESCE(postalcode + ' ', '') + street) 
END as Street
```

Comment: @mgo Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you  are using 2012,it has concat,may be you are trying it wrong way..here is syntax..

```
CASE 
   WHEN adres.CD_land = 'NL' THEN (street) 
   ELSE upper(concat(postalcode ,' ',street))
END as Street,
```